# Error: "Failed to open stream" on wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress search widget. Each time I search the results show but I also get this error:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/carshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/OpenDoor1.4/search.php on line 19

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home4/carshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/OpenDoor1.4sidebar-right' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home4/carshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/OpenDoor1.4/search.php on line 19
```

Comment: which is that plugin you are using?? And give your error log more clearly

Answer (score 1):

Please put '/' after 'OpenDoor1.4'in search.php on line 19 here is the problem

This path is wrong

```
/home4/carshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/OpenDoor1.4sidebar-right.php
```

Go open search.php and make it like this

```
/home4/carshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/OpenDoor1.4/sidebar-right.php
```

Reagrds,

Answer (score 0):

Using a Widget that came with the template. This is the best way i can show the error

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
in /home4/carshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/OpenDoor1.4/search.php on line 19

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 
'/home4/carshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/OpenDoor1.4sidebar-right' 
for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') 
in /home4/carshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/OpenDoor1.4/search.php on line 19
```